# coverage in parallel used all cpu resource

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm using coverage3.8, version 5.3 with C extension.

I used command: `coverage3.8 run --parallel-mode xxx.py` and used `htop` to check the CPU usage.  Then I found the CPU usage is off the chart.

I wonder if there is a variable/option that can set/limit how many CPU nodes that `coverage3.8`  can use?

Comment: Why do you need that?  Aren't you interested in coverage being calculated ASAP?

Comment: @KlasŠ. I'd like to run this program without using too much resource that other people on the same machine still have cpu resource to use.

Comment: I'd say don't worry about it, you're not the one to worry about CPU quotas.  Get your job done and let other people use all CPU resources afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--parallel-mode` just tells coverage to name the data files with a unique number so that more than one can be created at once. It doesn't cause processes to spawn.  Your program must be doing that.  What does your program do?

Comment: It turns out my program was set to multiple threads because of ```make -j {num_of_thread}``` It allows```make test``` using multiple thread and use the same number of threads

Answer (score 0):

Idk about `coverage` I normally use to run application with [taskset](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html). Works with most of the `debian` OS's.

If you want your program to use 3 CPU's

```
taskset --cpu-list 0-2 coverage3.8 run --parallel-mode xxx.py
```

similarly If you want your program to use 4 CPU's

```
taskset --cpu-list 0-3 coverage3.8 run --parallel-mode xxx.py
```